# ES6 Classes Event Emitter

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6

Can someone point me to a decent EventEmitter (ES6) to use emit events globally across different classes? Preferably with examples? I found quite a dozen, but none with working examples between classes..

I'd love one that works as a Singleton so I don't have to extend it..

For Example (not real code):

```
import emitter from 'SingleTonEmitter';
export class Listener(){
const myEmitter = new Emitter()
myEmitter.on('somethingHappened', (data) => this.onChange())
}

// NEW sepatate class
import emitter from 'SingleTonEmitter';
export class DispatchClass(){
const myEmitter = new Emitter()
myEmitter.dispatch('somethingHappened','optionalData')
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-emitter-es6)?

Comment: Found that one indeed, but you still need to extend it. I'll give it a go, thanks!

I Also found this one; https://github.com/oyed/eventkeeper

Approx. the same usage

Comment: Why would it be so important that it works as a singleton? You can trivially do that yourself: `export const myEmitter = new StandardEventEmitter();` in singletonemitter.js, then `import { myEmitter } from 'singletonEmitter'` in your files. And really *any* event emitter library could do that.

Answer (score 0):

RxJS subjects can act as general purpose event emitters. Singleton pattern is naturally handled by JS modules since they are evaluated only once and thus isn't specific to event emitter class implementation.

This is how it's done in RxJS 6:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const filterEvent = event => filter(e => e.event === event);

export default new Subject();
```

---

```
import emitter, { filterEvent } from './emitter';

emitter
.pipe(filterEvent('foo'))
// or
// .pipe(filter(({ event }) => event === 'foo')))
.subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e.data)
});

emitter.next({ event: 'foo', data: {...} });
```

RxJS `Subject` is used in [Angular `EventEmitter` implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.0/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts).

There are several subject classes that have their distinctive traits and may be preferred in some cases.

`Subject` class can be extended to provide syntactic sugar for `pipe(filter(...))` routine if necessary.